# Distributed computing, running code on one server on start

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku

I am running a nodejs server on heroku, using the throng package to spin up workers to process api requests. I am also using more than on dyno on heroku. For cron and job processing, I use bull queue to distribute the load across servers, but I came across something I am not sure how to do in this distributed environment.

I want to have only one server execute code immediately on startup. In this case, I want to open up a change stream listener for mongodb. But I only want to do this on one worker on one server, not every server.

I am not sure how to do this running in heroku, any suggestions?

Comment: more looking if someone has a strategy for executing code on boot up on only one worker when there are multiple workers on multiple servers.

Comment: Have you figured this out? I'm searching a solution for exact same problem.